# Cannot connect remote sql server on aliyun

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016, remote-access

I have installed SQL Server Developer Edition 2017 on Windows Server 2016 in order to do some test on my aliyun server.

However, I cannot connect remotely.

- On local SSMS, the "Allow remote connection to this server" is checked
- On local SSMS, I can login using the LAN ip of the server
- I have checked that the SQL Server configuration have TCP/IP enabled, and that the port is well set on IPALL config
- I have also enabled NAMED PIPES (we never know...)
- By default, the windows firewall is disabled (turn off) so I suppose that I don't have an issue there as well
- I can ping on my pc the distant server (public ip)
- I have rebooted the SQL SERVER service maybe a million times.

After all of it, I honestly have no idea what to do next to unlock this issue. Do you know if Aliyun block some port by default ? Do you know what can I check next to understand what's going on ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason... My guess was right. Aliyun have a firewall and you have to go to ECS Console management on Aliyun, Network and security, Security Group, then on the right on the first security group click on add rule, then the button Add Security Group Rule, then specify the MS port.